# storing protractor scripts and application code is same GIT repository

Tags: git, jenkins, protractor

I tried searching an answer to my question but not able to find any direct answer so some questions may look like too novice for someone.
I am new to Jenkins and GIT. Currently we are running our automated scripts manually once build is published but now we want to move to Jenkins and run automated scripts once a build is completed. My questions are:
1. Do we need to store protractor scripts and application code base in two seperate repositories? If not, is there any way we can store in two different Git repositories?
2. If we need to store in same repository, do I need to copy my protractor scripts in each project folder for each project?
3. Do I need to add two steps in my build programs? One for the code and one for running test scripts?

Appreciate your response.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer? Can someone please help?

Answer (score -1):

Answers to your questions

> 1. Do we need to store protractor scripts and application code base in two separate repositories? If not, is there any way we can store in
>      two different Git repositories?

Yes, you can store both tests & application code in same repository. If you want you can maintain them independent too if they are only e2e cases

> 2. If we need to store in same repository, do I need to copy my protractor scripts in each project folder for each project?

No, all your tests can be located at one place distributed into suites. Protractor supports execution based on suites as a CLI argument

> 3. Do I need to add two steps in my build programs? One for the code and one for running test scripts?

Depends on your approach to 1 & 2. If you are maintaining tests independently then you can have a post build step to trigger the tests or a separate Job2 which has Job1 as trigger.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way i can specify two GIT repository separately in my Jenkin job - one for my code and one for protractor scripts?